# How to read string containingg asterisk from a file in shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a file containing a number of lines as follows

```
source destination pattern
```

the pattern may have *.* also

When I read this pattern into a variable PATTERN using

```
cat $FILE_NAME|while read item
do
    arr=($item)
    PATTERN="${arr[2]}"
    echo "$PATTERN"
    done
```

then the output is some file in the working directory. How can I store "*.*" in PATTERN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing it the right way in the first place.

```
while read -a arr
do
    PATTERN="${arr[2]}"
    echo "$PATTERN"
done < "$FILE_NAME"
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams
I am new to shell scripting. It helped me a lot. I was stuck.